# WPF -- Animation Question

Tags: wpf, animation, triggers, storyboard

New to WPF.  Simple scenario.  Can't figure out the right way to do this.

Say I have a single Button.  I also have four TextBlocks.  I want that one button to trigger an animation (Opacity from 0 to 1) on all of the TextBlocks at the same time.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it...

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="OnClick1">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="button">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnClick1}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="button" Width="131" Height="37" Content="Button" Margin="0,0,0,22"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Height="27" Text="TextBlock 1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Opacity="0"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock1" Height="27" Text="TextBlock 2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Opacity="0"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock2" Height="27" Text="TextBlock 3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Opacity="0"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock3" Height="27" Text="TextBlock 4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Opacity="0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Isn't there a better way ? I'm not very experienced with animations, but it seems wrong to repeat the same thing 4 times...

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you...now, just to go a little deeper, what if I had a block of X TextBlocks, say in a Grid Column.  How could I assign the Storyboard to ALL TextBlocks in that grid without having to do an Animation for each one separately?

Comment: If you're going to have a lot of similar animations for a bunch of elements, you'll probably want to define it all in code and programmatically generate the animations for the storyboard.  AFAIK, there is no pure-Xaml way to do that.

Comment: There IS a pure-xaml way to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238515/wpf-its-gotta-be-easier-than-im-making-it/1239063#1239063

Comment: Nice trick. I posted a slight-variant of your solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238515/wpf-its-gotta-be-easier-than-im-making-it/1239565#1239565 that will work for multiple triggers without the need for adding a DataContext to the buttons.